# Error when trying to npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

new to this, I'm trying to install aws amplify from the command line and it keeps throwing me an err messages: I tried sudo, tried the safe route to no avail. I'm new to node and understanding dependencies etc. and not sure what I've done wrong!

```sh
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: graphql@14.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^14.5.8" from @aws-amplify/amplify-category-api@1.1.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/amplify-category-api
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/amplify-category-api@"1.1.10" from @aws-amplify/cli@7.6.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
npm ERR!       @aws-amplify/cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/amplify-category-api@"1.1.10" from amplify-container-hosting@2.4.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-container-hosting
npm ERR!       amplify-container-hosting@"2.4.10" from @aws-amplify/cli@7.6.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
npm ERR!         @aws-amplify/cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   graphql@"^14.5.8" from @aws-amplify/graphql-auth-transformer@0.5.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-auth-transformer
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/graphql-auth-transformer@"0.5.7" from @aws-amplify/cli@7.6.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
npm ERR!       @aws-amplify/cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!     @aws-amplify/graphql-auth-transformer@"0.5.7" from amplify-provider-awscloudformation@5.8.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-provider-awscloudformation
npm ERR!       amplify-provider-awscloudformation@"5.8.7" from @aws-amplify/cli@7.6.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli
npm ERR!         @aws-amplify/cli@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@aws-amplify/amplify-category-api, amplify-util-mock)
npm ERR!     1 more (@aws-amplify/graphql-relational-transformer)
npm ERR!   88 more (amplify-app, amplify-codegen, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^15.0.0" from relay-compiler@12.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-codegen-appsync-model-plugin/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common/node_modules/relay-compiler
npm ERR!   relay-compiler@"12.0.0" from @graphql-tools/relay-operation-optimizer@6.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-codegen-appsync-model-plugin/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common/node_modules/@graphql-tools/relay-operation-optimizer
npm ERR!     @graphql-tools/relay-operation-optimizer@"^6.3.7" from @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common@2.5.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-codegen-appsync-model-plugin/node_modules/@graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common
npm ERR!       @graphql-codegen/visitor-plugin-common@"^2.5.1" from amplify-codegen-appsync-model-plugin@1.24.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-codegen-appsync-model-plugin
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Can you add which node version are you using ? node --version

Comment: I have the same error using `node v16.5.0` and `npm 7.19.1` on Ubuntu. It worked after `npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 21):

run `npm install -g npm@latest`

and after that try installing `amplify-cli` again.