# Unable to get the version to change when performing a "npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest"

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Unable to get the version to change when performing a "npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@latest".  The version remains 4.29.2 when executing "amplify --version".

I followed the guide below but the version remained the same.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/721

I also tried the "npm install -g npm@latest" command and reinstalling amplify-cli from the link below.
[Error when trying to npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690871/error-when-trying-to-npm-install-g-aws-amplify-cli)

Comment: Have you tried [`amplify upgrade`](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/commands/upgrade/)?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When performing a npm upgrade @aws-amplify/cli the output says "up to date in 249ms".  When checking the version of @aws-amplify/cli, it remains version 4.29.2.